# MySQL_Connector stopped when trying to consume pending messages on ActiveMQ Queue

Tags: jdbc, jms, activemq-classic, mule

i'm doing some testing with ActiveMQ with failover and JDBC.

Happens that i accumulate pending messages with a dead consumer, the consumer has a JDBC insert query in it.

The consumer flow is like: JMS (Inbound) -> JDBC (Insert)

After having the pending messages waiting to be consumed, i start the consumer and start to get the messages, but when it tries to do the JDBC insertion of the data, i get a "MySQL_Connector is stopped".

Why is it? How can i solve this ? is there any way i could tell the JMS inbound to "wait" for the JDBC to start?

Thanks.

Comment: How did you configure the JDBC connector? Did it connect successfully on Mule startup?

Comment: imagine i got 100 pending messages waiting to be consumed by the consumer flow that has a JDBC insertion. I start the consumer project and easily 20 or 30 of those pending messages will fail because the MySQL Connector didn't start yet. The other 70 will succeed haha.

Comment: Mule version? This sounds like a bug.

Comment: I'm using Mule version 3.3.2.

Comment: Do you mind trying the same on 3.4?

Comment: let me check David. Happens that maybe i can't update from 3.3.2 since its an entire application already... we should need to migrate to 3.4 then :/

Comment: It's just a matter of checking if it's a solved issue or if we need to dig deeper here. If the problem persists, then please show the config of your JMS and JDBC connector, and flows that contain the JMS and JDBC endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to tackle this is to configure your connector in the order they will be used.

In fact mule starts the connectors in the order you declare them, and in case of JMS it can starts consuming message before the other connector has been started.

By putting the MySQL connector configuration before that the one of the JMS one you should be able to address this.